# Разделение в русском языке литературы и искусства

Tags: общие-вопросы

Литература в русском языке, на мой взгляд, как-то отделилась от искусства. В языковой практике, по крайней мере. Достаточно ли употребить слово "искусство", чтобы было понятно, что речь идёт обо всех видах художественного творчества, включая литературу, или в этом случае правильнее употребить словосочетание "искусство и литература"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть, сказать "литература и другие виды искусства"? Литература всё-таки тоже искусство - искусство слова

Слово «искусство» многозначно, в данном случае им названа собственно художественная деятельность и то, что является ее результатом (произведение). В разных видах искусства действует один и тот же закон: бессодержательный материал организуется художником в жизнеподобную форму, выражающую определенное идейно-эстетическое содержание. При этом каждый вид искусства использует «свой» материал: музыка — звук, живопись — краски, архитектура — камень, дерево, металл и т. д. Специфика художественной литературы заключается в том, что это — вид искусства, использующий в качестве единственного материала слова и конструкции человеческого языка. Таким образом, литература — это искусство слова.

"Литература и искусство",на мой взгляд, звучит некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Comment: "Специфика художественной литературы заключается в том, что это — вид искусства, использующий в качестве единственного материала слова и конструкции человеческого языка." А как же литеры? Без буковок не получится.

Answer (score -1):

Нет, без слова "литература" искусство - это именно искусство. В которое литература не входит.
Да, собственно, и так не очень понятно, почему литература - искусство, а не наука, скажем? Литература не "отделилась", она всегда была чем-то самостоятельным. Думаю, что и музыка тоже "не искусство". Но тут я полный профан, настаивать не буду.

Comment: **Искусство** могут связывать с **творчеством** и **мастерством** и иногда противопоставлять **ремеслу**. Ремесло -- это технология, набор повторяющихся в разных вариациях не особо сложных действий. Вот по поводу музыки. К примеру, **так** как я играю на гитаре -- это не искусство. :-) Несколько аккордов выучить, как я, это дело нехитрое. Моя племянница несколько лет ходит в музыкальную школу и на фортепиано уже умеет играть непростые вещи. Это определённое мастерство, и, как мне кажется, уже ближе к искусству. Думаю, что **ХОРОШИЙ музыкант** -- это искусство.

Comment: Мы говорили о *восприятии*. Оно субъективно. Могут связать - а могут и не связать. Я не связываю. Думаю, что так мыслит и большинство. Могу ошибаться.